# Trouble displaying MS Word html file in Asp.Net Literal Control

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, literals

When I display an html file that was created in MS Word, it doesn't render correctly in the ASP Literal control.  It seems to have trouble showing tabs, dashes, bullets, etc.  Is there something I can do to make this work?

Comment: Or is there a way to strip this out in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some characters from MSWord will never appear correct: tabs, bullets, dashes. You could use XL instead of Word and create a macro that changes the bullets to **&bull;** or dashes to **&minus;**.  I dont think tabs have an html equivilent.

Others characters (international) can only be shown if both your ascx and aspx are both UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Thank you.  These docs were/are created by a different dept.  However, we have decided (read my boss) that these minor issues are better left alone.  So, I don't have to fix this after all.